Can’t make a small working project starting with Application Insights
I wanted to create a small, hello world, single application page web site and I keep having errors.  I searched for the error, implemented the proposed changes and other issues happenend.
Could you please help me understand the issue, I don’t want server components, only typescript and html  running on NodeJs as I understood Application Insights won’t work without NodeJs working with VSCode on Windows 10.
App.ts
import * as appInsights from '../node_modules/applicationinsights/out/applicationinsights.js';

function main(_t: number): void {
  appInsights.setup('***').start();
}

main(1);

package.json
{
  "main": "./js/app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set DEBUG_MODE=true && start python -m http.server 1973 && start http://localhost:1973"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.8.10",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "applicationinsights": "^2.9.5"
  }
}

tsConfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "outDir": "./js",
    "rootDir": "./ts", 
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./ts/**/*.ts", "@types/**/*.d.ts"]
}

I used '../node_modules/applicationinsights/out/applicationinsights.js' as I had the message: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "applicationinsights". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
If you can provide any help, thanks.


only typescript and html on NodeJs as I understood Application Insights won’t work without NodeJs in this configuration, working with VSCode on Windows 10.


As I provided in the previous solution. I just want to clarify some details. Firstly, please downgrade your node version to 18.0.X, if you use 20.0.X v.


I wanted to create a small, hello world

Please follow the below steps.

Initialize a New npm Project with npm init -y



Install applicationinsights@3.0.0-beta.




Create a TypeScript Configuration File npx tsc --init



Create a app.ts file in the project directory and the below code.

import * as appInsights from 'applicationinsights';

// Set up Application Insights
appInsights.setup('InstrumentationKey').start();

// Example: Track a custom event
const client = appInsights.defaultClient;
client.trackEvent({ name: 'MyCustomEvent', properties: { key: 'value' } });

console.log('Message logged to Application Insights.');


Compile TypeScript to JavaScript with npx tsc


Executed:

Result:

Package.json:
{
  "name": "rxjsclient",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^3.1.2",
    "applicationinsights": "^3.0.0-beta.12",
    "typescript": "^5.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.5"
  }
}


Thanks a lot for helping me again, I was lost :(   I had this error message when I ran npx tsc --init outside of Powershell but then I reinstalled typescript and it finally worked.  Thanks a lot.

I went back on this test project and it seems now that it builds but I have an error message at runtime :(        An invalid connection string was passed in. There may be telemetry loss [ '**' ] No instrumentation key or connection string was provided to the Azure Monitor Exporter [].   I went back on Azure Portal, tested with the connection string and with the instrumentation key, I can't see what is missing. If you would have any idea... thanks !
